# Login with curl - PHP

Tags: php, ssl, curl

i want to write a script to log in uses curl in PHP. I wrote this code and when i try to use this script, all the time shows message: "Username or Password is incorrect", but if I give this same username and pass, I will log in.

I have no idea what this system requires more, my code now looks like:

```
    $curl=curl_init("http://plemiona.pl/page/auth");
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0");
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_REFERER,"http://plemiona.pl/");
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);   
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  0);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "D:\cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "D:\cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                                                "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",
                                                "POST /page/auth HTTP/1.1", 
                                                "Host: www.plemiona.pl",
                                                "Accept: */*",
                                                "Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3",
                                                "Content-Length: 48"));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$postVars = array('username' => 'username', 
                      'password' => 'pass', 
                      'remember' => '0',);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postVars);        
    $dw=curl_exec($curl);
    echo $dw;
```

When i try manual log in, firefox http headers will show:

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/funSl.png)
[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG1rK.png)

My file with cookies after send POST with a curl:
`.plemiona.pl   TRUE    /   FALSE   1520687485  cid 705415657`

So nothing :(

It is possible that i have to use correct SSL certificate to use: curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE) ?
Or what should i search to repair it?

Comment: Look into the request headers maybe you missing something in post fields

Comment: it's not probably. There are no more fields :(
http://i.imgur.com/WXLiE7j.png

Comment: Did you tried to remove CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE ?

Comment: yes, no change :( i dont know where i should search a problem :(